# A problem with benzene ring and chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I want to create a Benzene ring with carbon atoms placed at the six nodes of the ring. I am using `chemfig` package to achieve this. But it so happens that the bond is actually going into the carbon atom at one of the sites. 
[image]

MWE and output is appended below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{*6(C(-H)=C(-H)-C(-H)=C(-H)-C(-H)=C(-H)-)}

\end{document}
```

Ideally all the bond lengths should be the same, but somehow only on the atom seems to be a problem. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, got the correct configuration by moving the first Carbon atom outside the ring.

`\chemfig{C*6((-H)=C(-H)-C(-H)=C(-H)-C(-H)=C(-H)-)}`

Comment: More information on this topic can be found in chapter 10 of the [`chemfig` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig): '`chemfig` can easily draw regular polygons. The idea is to attach a ring to an `<atom>` outside the ring with this syntax: `<atom>*<n>(<code>)<n>`is the number of sides of the polygon and the `<code>` describes the bonds and groups of atoms which makeup its edges and vertices. This code mustbegin with a bond because the atom is outside the ring.'